# no 'void TestSub::print()' member function declared in class 'TestSub'

Tags: c++

parent class

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(){};
    virtual ~Test(){};
    void print() {  cout<<1<<endl;};
};
```

sub class .h define

```
class TestSub: public Test {
public:
    TestSub();
    virtual ~TestSub();
 };
```

sub class .cpp implements

```
#include "TestSub.h"

TestSub::TestSub() {

}

TestSub::~TestSub() {
}

void TestSub::print(){
    cout<<2<<endl;
}

int main(){
    TestSub *t=new TestSub();
    t->print();
}
```

why:

..\src\TestSub.cpp:17:21: error: no 'void TestSub::print()' member function declared in class 'TestSub'

Comment: You forgot the type.. Do `void TestSub::print()` instead.

Comment: I do as you mentioned,  but popup no 'void TestSub::print()'

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors:

- First you have to declare you function in `TestSub` as : `void print();`
- Second you have to specify a return type for you implementation, C++ do not accept default return type such as `C`, so you must convert your implementation to `void TestSub::print() {...}`

Comment: I can't understand why testsub should declare void print(), it is extended from test which has print method. Thanks for your explain

Comment: You are right, it is derived from `Test`, but how compiler should know that you want to change implementation of base class, unless you say that in your class?

Answer (score 1):

print() funciton is not declared in TestSub class.

```
class TestSub: public Test {
public:
    TestSub();
    void print();        // add declaration.
    virtual ~TestSub();
 };
```

I guess you also intended to make `Test::print` virtual?

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(){}
    virtual ~Test(){}
    virtual void print() {  std::cout << 1 << std::endl;} 
};
```

Comment: Testsub extended Test, so it must has the print method, why still need declare it?

Comment: because you tried to define it again `void TestSub::print()`. if you want to Test::print to print `1` and TestSub::print to print 2, you need to make Test::print virtual and override in TestSub. This eventually leads to function polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the return type C defaults to int as return type of a function. Which doesn't match the void return type of the declaration in the class.